# If my domain is on the IE Compatibility View List, can It still be forced to be on standards mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

It is valid html5, it has the `<!doctype html>` and also the meta tags in the `<head>` section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```